# GitLab CI, monorepo and feature branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, monorepo, feature-branch

I have a monorepo in GitLab with a Feature Branch approach.

What I'm trying to achieve is to launch the part of the pipeline associated to the directory containing the altered files. So my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like :

```
job1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ...
  only:
    changes:
      - myparentdir/dir1/*

job2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ...
  only:
    changes:
      - myparentdir/dir2/*
```

1. Create a new branch from develop
2. Commit myparentdir/dir2/test.txt on this branch
3. The pipeline launch every build jobs !

It seems like GitLab is considering every files as altered when working with a new feature branch.

Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gitlab ci always treats `changes` for new branches as true. The reason is that they can't decide what to compare against.

> what this means is that for the first pipeline of a new branch, everything will be built.

See the [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19232#behavior-in-new-branch-case) for more details.

But, there is a fairly new feature called Pipelines for [merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/) - that runs a stage on merge requests. [Here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/24490) is the feature request that implements `changes` with merge_requests. It's merged, but I'm not sure if it's already released. (the milestone is 11.9 - the next release)

In the meantime you can implement it yourself - You can add a stage that compares the changes (git diff) and decides whether to run the next stage:

```
.store_diff_from_main: &store_diff_from_main |
  git diff --name-only origin/master...HEAD > "${DIFF_FILE}"
  git diff --name-only HEAD~1 >> "${DIFF_FILE}"

.skip_stage: &skip_stage_condition |
  echo Checking for changes in ${STAGE_PATHS}, changed files
  # https://coderwall.com/p/gecfwa/git-diff-vs
  cat .diff-from-master
  # also cover merge squash cases
  if ! (cat ${DIFF_FILE} | grep -E "${STAGE_PATHS}"); then
    echo "Skipping stage ..."
    exit 0
  fi
```

Comment: It seems good. For now, I can't affirm that it solve my problem because I have difficulties for implementing this with windows batch : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105278/gitlab-runner-on-windows-and-dealing-with-errorlevel?noredirect=1#comment96958039_55105278

Comment: It works. The problem is that all my 126 jobs are launched, 125 are skipped but still appeared on my pipeline...

Comment: that's the problem with this solution - it's not native - so the jobs will start but will be skipped. I am also waiting for the native solution

Comment: `only: changes` combined with `only: refs: - merge_requests` appears to allow me to have code specific pipelines but has strange behavior because "The behavior of the only: merge_requests parameter is such that only jobs with that parameter are run in the context of a merge request; no other jobs will be run." from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/, so I can't have some jobs apply to all code changes and other jobs that are filepath specific.

Comment: @mmacvicar you are right. In my case I have the branch master and feature branches. If I want for some stage to run for PR and for master I add - master after the merge_request line